# Python - Calling two parent __init__() methods with different number of arguments

Tags: python, constructor, multiple-inheritance

Hi I'm having problem finding an answer to this question so I will ask it here.

I'm trying to call the **init** function of two parents classes but I don't really know how to do it regarding syntax.

Here are the classes

```
from IsVisible import *
class Shape(IsVisible):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Shape, self).__init__() 
        self.posSize = []
    def getPosSize(self):
        return self.posSize

class Rectangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Rectangle, self).__init__()
        self.color = self.blue
        self.posSize = [20,50,100,100]

class Movable:
    def __init__(self, fps):

        self.deltaX = self.__xStartSpeedPerSec/fps
        self.deltaY = self.__yStartSpeedPerSec/fps

    __xStartSpeedPerSec = 0.0
    __yStartSpeedPerSec = 0.0

class Mob(Rectangle, Movable):
    def __init__(self, fps):
        super(Mob, self).__init__()
        super(Mob, self).__init__(fps)
```

So the class Mob is the child here with the parent Shape and Movable. I want to call both **init**() fucntions of Shape and Movable from the **init** function of Mob. However my current implementation of doing so with super is not working.
Im getting the error:

```
    super(Mob, self).__init__(fps)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

So, my question is. How do I call the **init** methods of the two parents when they have a different number of arguments?

Comment: `super` is for *cooperative* multitasking: it implicitly assumes that all the classes in the MRO are using `super` properly as well. Further, each `__init__` needs to know how to deal with unexpected, arbitrary arguments.

Comment: @chepner Thx for your answer! However I feel like I might be a bit under the level you're talking with. Do you mean that my other classes are not using super as they should? And I've never really thought about the dealing with unexpected arguments before. I thought it was abit over my level.

Comment: I'd recommend reading [Python’s super() considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) first, then [Python's Super is nifty, but you can't use it](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/), which points out some issues that the first link addresses indirectly. In a nutshell, your `Movable` either needs to be rewritten, or you need to define an adaptor for it; the other classes might need to be modified as well.

Comment: In what way does it need to be modified? And what is an adaptor? Am I not supposed to use super at all and use something else instead?